# FreeSwitch Create Extension/SIP User using API

Tags: android, .net, freeswitch, pbx, fusionpbx

I have been following this

```
http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Webapi
http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Mod_commands
```

For using the webapi to communicate to the Freeswitch server to execute commands.

Isnt there a command to create extensions?

If their isnt then how to programmatically create an extension?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

your tags for this question are completely misleading.
I don't know if FusionPBX provide such an API.

FreeSWITCH can read the users directory from static XML files or from XML documents delivered by some HTTP server. So, you can build such HTTP service and deliver the user extensions to FreeSWITCH.

For more details, see http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Mod_xml_curl